# What are the unique shapes of the weapons control switches in a F-14?

Tags: military, flight-training, cockpit

In his answer to the question [Muscle memory for weapons systems?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/73830/muscle-memory-for-weapons-systems/73832#73832) Michael Hall mentioned "'blind fold cockpit checks'... (learning to) locate certain switches by feel, reinforcing muscle memory to both locate them and identify them by their often unique shape."

These [illustrations](https://www.globalsecurity.org/military/library/policy/navy/nrtc/14313_ch15.pdf) of F-14 control panels 
  [image]

F-14 weapons control panels, and

[image]
F-14 control panel

show the [switchology](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/switchology) (hey, I learned a new word) of the aircraft.

I don't see any distinct differences in the shapes in these diagrams.  What at the different shapes used in an F-14 to distinguish switches by feel?  Are there any other clues to help in the assistance of locating by feel?

If information about the shapes of switches (or other means to identify by feel) in other combat aircraft is available as an alternative, that would suffice to answer my question.

Comment: [This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/22680/62) covers civilian aircraft, but it's related

Comment: I think your question needs to be more specific.  First, whose military are you asking about?  I can't imagine that a MiG-25 would have much in common with an F-14, or a British Harrier or whatever the French are making these days.  And second, is there even commonality between aircraft of one country?  Is the F-35 the same as the F-14 or F-16?